# Скачать: с или из?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно сказать: "скачать файл из компьютера" или "с компьютера"? Аналогичная ситуация с "скачать с интернета (сайта)" или "из интернета (сайта)". По идее, речь идет об извлечении информации ИЗ памяти компьютера или ИЗ ресурсов какого-то сайта. Но в обычной речи чаще можно услышать все-таки "скачать с (чего-то)". Что это: просторечная форма или все-таки правильное употребление слова? Либо же допустимы оба варианта употребления?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: скачать с чего-либо. Правило такое: На- С, В -Из. (  http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=13.8 ) Однако, в некоторых случаях ,это правило действует не всегда. В этих случаях употребление предлогов в (из) или на (с) определяется традицией.Некоторые нормы со временем изменились:  пойти в концерт (до начала XX века) → пойти на концерт. См., например, «Маскарад М. Ю. Лермонтова:
Нина

Князь, вы сошли с ума — на вас
Теперь сердиться было б стыдно.

Князь

Прощайте навсегда — прошу в последний раз...

Нина

Куда ж вы едете, далеко очень, видно;
Конечно, не в луну?

Князь

‎Нет, ближе: на Кавказ.

Answer (score 4):

При выборе нужного предлога сказывается влияние следующих факторов:

1)  ПРОСТРАНСТВО ИЛИ ПЛОСКОСТЬ

Следует различать по смыслу:  (1) скачать из Интернета, (2) скачать с сайта.

Вариант 1 предполагает наличие пространственного предмета, из которого извлекается информация. Таким предметом, то есть Всемирной компьютерной  сетью, является Интернет.

Вариант 2  предполагает, что информация находится на виртуальной плоскости (сайте), с поверхности которой  мы скачиваем нужный материал.

2) СКАЧАТЬ С : поддержка  предлога С одноименной приставкой С

Компьютер можно воспринимать и как пространство, и как плоскость, поэтому можно встретить оба варианта, например:  (1) «скачать с компьютера на телефон»  и  (2)«скачать из компьютера на телефон». Но с учетом  влияния приставки С выражение (1) кажется более грамотным.